# How to control <li> list item visibility using Eval

Tags: asp.net, eval

In an unordered list the visibility of individual list items can be set thus:

```
<li runat="server" visible=false>Apples</li>
```

or:

```
<li runat="server" visible="false">Bananas</li>
```

But why can't this be done using the 'Eval'method? None of these work:

```
<li runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("Show")%>'>Carrots</li>
```

--where Show is a bit that has values of 0 or 1.

```
<li runat="server" visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Show"))%>'>Dill</li>
```

--where Show is a string that has values "true" or "false", or an integer that is either 0 or 1.

What is the answer?

Comment: _"why can't this be done"_ ... _"None of these work"_ can you be a little bit more specific? What is the result, an error?

Comment: Many thanks for your help Tim.We had a deeper error elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<li runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("Show").ToString() == "1" %>' ID="bananaItem">Bananas</li>
```

If that doesn't work, you could also use codebehind if it has `runat="server"` and an ID:

With CSS (available at client-side):

```
// make it invisible
bananaItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none");
// make it visible:
bananaItem.Attributes.CssStyle.Remove("display");
```

`Visible`-property (not available at client-side, isn't rendered at all):

```
bananaItem.Visible = false;
```